# How to set height and width of an image object in js

Tags: javascript

I have this array of image objects and I want to set the height and width if possible inside the array, because I have tons of images which I put in a table and I want them all to be the same size. Any ideas?

```
function myFunction(){   
    var imagelist = [{"image":"image3.jpg"}];
}
```

Comment: *"I have tons of images which I put in a table and I want them all to be the same size"* - that's exactly what CSS is designed for. Create a CSS class `table-image`, use it for every image.

Comment: *"I want them all to be the same size"* - So apply the size *once* with a CSS rule in your style sheet. You don't need to apply a class to every image, apply it to the table and use a selector like `.tableClass img`.

Comment: You show the code of some configs of your image list, but depends on how you manipulate your image list, there maybe different methods, can you post more code, like what would you do with your imagelist afterwards?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev The thing is that this is part of a school project. I am not supposed to use css.

Comment: If you got use js, you can just loop the array: `imgs.forEach()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function resizeImg(img, height, width) {
    img.height = height;
    img.width = width;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.lawctopus.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/new-google-logo.jpg"  onload="resizeImg(this, 200, 100);">
```

Here i create function through which you can set your image `height` and `width`.